# Send an image via TCP sockets from node.js to Qt client

Tags: node.js, sockets, image-processing, tcp

I want to open an image and send it and send to the sockets that are connected in my nodejs server.
The problem is when I'm trying to send some image via `socket.write(myImage);` because the method `write()` can't send it as an image object. The "solution" that i've found is to create a buffer from my image, copy in another buffer and parse it to a base64 encode and send this using `socket.write(myBase64Img)`, receive it in my Qt client and decode that image with openCV. the problem is that this is very expensive. There is another way to send my image via TCP sockets?

PS: I can't send the URL of the image, I want to send the image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write the raw image data to the socket without base64-encoding it, just pass a Buffer containing that binary data to `write()`. You could also stream the data if you don't have the image completely in memory already since that would help save on memory usage.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: @Tomirammstein It depends on where your image data is stored. Do you have the binary image data in a Buffer? Do you have it on disk and not in memory yet? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're dealing with an image that is already on disk, the right way to do this is to stream the image directly from disk to the socket.

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
stream.pipe(socket);
```

See the docs for details:

- [`fs.createReadStream`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)
- [`Stream#pipe`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)